# How do I mirror a private google site?

Tags: wget, google-sites

We have an internal wiki hosted on google sites. It's only accessible to persons in our organization (we have a G Suite Domain).

I need to make a mirror of it (because we're moving some things to a different service and I don't want to copy/paste the contents).

I've tried playing with wget, but I don't understand how to give it sufficient credentials to log in (I've presently got two-factor auth enabled, but I can disable that if needed).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make the site such that anyone with the link can access it, then you can mirror through that link. It's far from optimal, but for a one-time dump it may be an acceptable way to proceed.